# How do I create a local server in packaged chrome app which runs offline?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-app, localserver

I want to create a Node.js server in chrome app so that I would be able to run node.js applications through it. The app would run offine therefore the server had to be local.

Comment: I know that a normal HTTP web server could be created, but I want to create a custom server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to do my setup in Chrome app, I used node-webkit for making my project to work and setup my project as

**General Information**
`Express Server` is started on port no `3000`.
`EJS` is used for HTML renderer for ExpressJS
`PeerJS Server` is started on port no `9000`.
`IndexedDB` is used for database purposes.
`PouchDB` is used as wrapper for IndexedDB
`blueimp-file-upload` is used for FTP over express server.
`AngularJS` is used for creating modules for front-end.
`LUMX` is used as UI framework.
`jQuery is used for DOM Manipulation`.
`Velocity` is used for smoother animations.

Complete code can be found at my github pulic repo
https://github.com/sumitkumar1209/PQ-PinQuip-Messenger

Comment: It's not a Node.js server "in a Chrome app", you still use a lot of external (even though local) servers. So this is not a correct answer for your own question.

Comment: yeah, I mentioned that in my first line that I used node-webkit for making my project to work.